# How to cite a complete figure which contains several subfigures extending over multiple pages

Tags: subfloats

I would like to cite a complete figure (say Fig.1) which contains several sub-figures (say a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) and extends over next page. Here is the code which I used.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]    
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}    
\makebox[\textwidth][c]  
{  
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b.png}}     
}\\ [2ex]  
\makebox[\textwidth][c]  
{  
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{c.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{d.png}}  
}\\ [2ex]    
\makebox[\textwidth][c]    
{
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{e.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{f.png}}   
}  
\caption{}  
\end{figure}  
% The Figure continues on the next page  
\begin{figure}  
\ContinuedFloat  
\makebox[\textwidth][c]  
{  
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{g.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{h.png}}  
}       
\caption{this is figure 1 a-h.}  
\label{fig:fig1}  
\end{figure}
```

When I try to cite the whole figure in my document, it is always cited as Fig.1h. I would like to cite the whole figure as only Fig.1 and its individual sub-figure as Fig.1a, Fig.1b, Fig.1c....Fig.1h manually when necessary.

Many thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions !!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick question: Which package, or packages, do you load to provide subfigure functionality?

Comment: Hi Mico, I use subfig package to get subfigure functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ LaRiFaRi I have solved the problem using the same original code which I posted in the begining.The solution was pretty simple though. Here is the code which I used, perhaps others with similar difficulty might get benifited :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]    
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}    
\makebox[\textwidth][c]  
{  
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{b.png}}     
}\\ [2ex]  
\makebox[\textwidth][c]  
{  
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{c.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{d.png}}  
}\\ [2ex]    
\makebox[\textwidth][c]    
{
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{e.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{f.png}}   
}  
\caption{}
\label{fig:fig1}  
\end{figure}  
% The Figure continues on the next page  
\begin{figure}  
\ContinuedFloat  
\makebox[\textwidth][c]  
{  
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{g.png}} \quad
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{h.png}}  
}       
\caption{this is figure 1 a-h.}  
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Notice that I have moved \label before \ContinuedFloat. This solved the problem without doing anything else. Now I can refer to the whole figure as Fig.1 and its subfigures as Fig.1a etc. Thanks LaRiFaRi for your suggestions which finally led me to the solution...

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `subfig` usually and prefer `subcaption`, but as I don't know, how the `\ContinuedFloat` is done there, here is a solution for `subfig`.

You always can pass a `\label{fig:...}` after your `\includegraphics{...}` command. Referencing will work than, but the lector has to know, what you mean by "figure 1h". Therefore you need captions. The `[]` next to `\subfig` just switches on the "(a)", "(b)" ... You may want to fill the brackets to get a real caption as well.

I tidied up your code a bit. It still has all your functionality.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    ,demo
    ]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb] 
\centering   
\subfloat[][opt. caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{a}\label{fig:Figurea}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{b}\label{fig:Figureb}} \\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{c}\label{fig:Figurec}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{d}\label{fig:Figured}}  \\ 
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{e}\label{fig:Figuree}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{f}\label{fig:Figuref}}    
\phantomcaption % for caption version 3.2 or higher. Not needed if not used with subfig.  
\end{figure}  
 The Figure continues on the next page  
\begin{figure}  
\centering
\ContinuedFloat  
\subfloat[][opt. caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{g}\label{fig:Figureg}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{h}\label{fig:Figureh}}    
\caption{These are figures 1 a-h}  
\label{fig:fig1}  
\end{figure}  
This is figure \ref{fig:fig1} and its subfigure \ref{fig:Figuref} or \ref{fig:Figureh}.
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

As `hyperref` and `\ContinuedFload` don't work together, here is an example showing the use of the `subcaption`-package. I just found out, that `\ContinuedFload` can be used here as well.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    ,demo
    ]{graphicx}
\usepackage[%
    ,hypcap=true
    ]{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\phantomcaption % for caption version 3.2 or higher. Not needed if not uses with subfig.
\label{fig:fig1}  
\centering   
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}\caption{opt. caption}\label{fig:Figurea}}\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}\caption{}\label{fig:Figureb}}\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c}\caption{}\label{fig:Figurec}}\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{d}\caption{}\label{fig:Figured}}\end{subfigure}  \\ 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{e}\caption{}\label{fig:Figuree}}\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{f}\caption{}\label{fig:Figuref}}\end{subfigure}     
\end{figure}  
% the Figure continues on the next page  
\begin{figure}  
\centering
\ContinuedFloat  
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{g}\caption{opt. caption}\label{fig:Figureg}}\end{subfigure} \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}{\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{h}\caption{}\label{fig:Figureh}}\end{subfigure}    
\caption{These are figures 1 a-h}    
\end{figure}
This is figure \ref{fig:fig1} and its subfigure \ref{fig:Figuref} or \ref{fig:Figureh}.
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

One more comment on that. It is not good practice, not to use a caption on the first page. The reader expects to get an information at the same place as the figure and not later. Therefore you should think about adding a caption to each figure:

```
\caption[These are figures 1 a-h]{These are figures 1 a-h (\emph{continued on next page})} 
\label{fig:fig1}    
\end{figure} 

...

\caption[]{These are figures 1 a-h}    
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, I am using latex code to layout my document for a particular journal which does not allow me to use hyperref package and without hyperref package hypcap won't work. Could you please recommend me any other manual way to solve this problem. I used subfig package to get subfigure functionality. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, if you don't use `hyperref`, you don't need `hypcap`. Just kick these two packages out. Referencing works without that two. Hypcap would be cool, if you actually use links. "Solve this problem", is some problem left?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code but the problem still persists. Let me redefine what is the problem. I want to reference the whole figure (which contains 8 subfigures a,b..,h and extends to multiple pages) as "Fig.1". However, when i use your code it is referenced as "Fig.1h" (even my code without [] after \subfloat gives the same result). What I want is, to get rid of "h" from "Fig.1h" when I reference that figure in my document. Many thanks !!

Comment: Please just compile the code above. With nothing else. I am getting "This is figure 1 and its subfigure 1h". I deleted the lines with `hypcap` and `hyperref` completely.

Comment: I tried the same thing but doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Since the `subfig` package loads the `caption` package the `hypcap` package isn't needed at all, in fact it could even reduce the number of correct hyperlinks. (See `caption` doc about the build-in "hypcap" feature.)

Comment: @JKR Does my update work for you?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi No it did not...I have also tried to compare the output with yours (which you posted last week) but it looks slightly different in my case...I guess the problem could be the journal-specific latex code which I use to produce the document..

Comment: Yes, sure it does. Please just try my example. It is a complete document. Leave anything else away. If that works, your system is OK. In this case, you have to add the requirements of your journal until the result breaks and post the minimal not working case to your question.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I am trying that option..I will update you with the result...