# Why does hyperref break the labels of subfigures with ContinuedFload?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

This is a follow up to here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130629/32245

When I insert `\usepackage{hyperref}` as last line of the preamble. The main figure (or the two continued figures) are labeled as "0" but the sub-figures as "1a - 1h". Why is that so?

In the comments on the linked post, it is mentioned, that `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` is not needed due to the `caption`-package loaded by `subfig`. However, I don't succeed to hyperlink to the top of all sub-figures instead of the caption on the second page. I even tried `\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}` before and after loading `subfig`.

---

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    ,demo
    ]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}    
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!htb] 
\centering   
\subfloat[][opt. caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{a}\label{fig:Figurea}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{b}\label{fig:Figureb}} \\
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{c}\label{fig:Figurec}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{d}\label{fig:Figured}}  \\ 
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{e}\label{fig:Figuree}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{f}\label{fig:Figuref}}    
\phantomcaption % for caption version 3.2 or higher. Not needed if not used with subfig.  
\end{figure}  
% The figure continues on the next page  
\begin{figure}  
\centering
\ContinuedFloat  
\subfloat[][opt. caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{g}\label{fig:Figureg}} \hfill
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{h}\label{fig:Figureh}}    
\caption{These are figures 1 a-h}  
\label{fig:fig1}  
\end{figure}  

This is figure \ref{fig:fig1} and its subfigure \ref{fig:Figureh}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem can be simplified a lot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{abc}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{cde}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would put the blame on subfig (it redefines some important commands at the begin of the document and so breaks the `\ContinuedFloat` command) but probably only the author of caption can do something about it.

I personally would avoid subfig and use the `subcaption` package instead.

Comment: Thanks. I always do use `subcaption`. I only tried to help in the linked question where `subfig` is used and found that error there. I will provide a `subcaption`-answer now.

Comment: The `hypcap`-functionality does not work for me. Maybe you could take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130629/32245 . I would like to jump always to the top of the referenced figure or sub-figure. But it still jumps to the caption.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Works fine for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you jump to the top edge of Figure 1a when pressing on the reference to Figure 1?

Comment: Naturally not. The label is in the second figure and so also the jump target. If you want a target in the first figure move the `\phantomcaption` at the begin and add a `\label`.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I don't think it's naturally. The `\ContinuedFload` merges to figures to one. They are sharing a caption. Why not also the label? Second concern: Why do I have to put the phantom caption to the top, when `hypcap=true` is set? I thought, captions are ignored then, but the top of the figure is linked.

Comment: It is not natural not to use a caption in the first figure. How should the reader know that the explanations will follow later?

Comment: Yes, that's true, also. I will add that to my answer in the other post.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately the way how `figure` and `table` counters are treated differs a lot between the `caption` and `subfig` package in current versions. (It's a pity that the `subfig` package is not maintained anymore.) But I'll see if I can do something to get this working again: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/16/

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The top of the figure is only linked if a `\label` is following the `\phantomcaption` and if you are linking to that label. Why is the label not shared? First of all this would omit the opportunity to create a (hyper)link which is pointing to a specific part of the (continued) float. And second I (and Steven) simply did not thought about this ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I can't think of a case where I would like to point to a specific part. Or I refer to a subfigure or to the whole thing. If I would like to refer to the second block (page), a second figure would make more sense.