# Continued figures

Tags: floats

```
        %This is figure 1
        \begin{figure}
          \centering
          \caption{blahblah}
          \label{figure1}

        \vspace{0.5 cm}

        \begin{center}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A
        \end{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s1.pdf}

        \vspace{1 cm}

        \begin{center}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel B
        \end{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s2.pdf}


        \end{figure}


        %This is Figure 1 continued
        \begin{figure}
        \vspace{-1.8cm}
          \centering
          \caption{blahblah}
          \label{figure1cont}

        \vspace{0.5 cm}

        \begin{center}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel C: Bank $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD}
        \end{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s3.pdf}

        \vspace{8 cm}


        \end{figure}


%This is figure 2
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{blahblah}
  \label{figure2}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s4.pdf}

\vspace{1 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel B
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s5.pdf}

\end{figure}
```

---

When I use the above, I get my first figure is called Figure 1, however the second figure (which is meant to be called Figure 1 (Cont.)) appears as Figure 2 on the next page and the final figure (which is meant to be called Figure 2) appears as Figure 3.

I also tried using `subfig` package with `\ContinuedFloat`:

```
        %This is figure 1
        \begin{figure}
          \centering
          \caption{blahblah}
          \label{figure1}

        \vspace{0.5 cm}

        \begin{center}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A
        \end{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s1.pdf}

        \vspace{1 cm}

        \begin{center}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel B
        \end{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s2.pdf}


        \end{figure}


        %This is Figure 1 continued
        \begin{figure}
        \vspace{-1.8cm}

         %Using ContinuedFloat here 

      \ContinuedFloat
          \centering
          \caption{blahblah}
          \label{figure1cont}

        \vspace{0.5 cm}

        \begin{center}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel C: Bank $\Delta$\textit{CoJPoD}
        \end{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s3.pdf}

        \vspace{8 cm}


        \end{figure}


%This is figure 2
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{blahblah}
  \label{figure2}

\vspace{0.5 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel A
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s4.pdf}

\vspace{1 cm}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont Panel B
\end{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{s5.pdf}

\end{figure}
```

But all this does is it makes my first figure called "Figure 1", then my Figure 1 continued figure is named as "Figure 0" and the figure that's meant to be my Figure 2 called Figure 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your first attempt you have to know that the `\label{}` command does not define the way your figure (or table, etc.) is named in your output. It defines the key you will have to use to make some cross-reference to this figure. You should have a look at the command `\thefigure` linked to the `figure` counter.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131181/why-does-hyperref-break-the-labels-of-subfigures-with-continuedfloat

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this approach. It uses `\ContinuedFloat` from »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« together with a new caption format `cont` for a continued figure by `\DeclareCaptionFormat` in the preamble. Furthermore the continued figure will not appear in the LoF. If you don't want that, just drop `\captionsetup` in the continued figure.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}  % only to bring all on one page
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{cont}{#1 (cont.)#2#3\par}

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First figure}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \ContinuedFloat
    \captionsetup{list=off,format=cont}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}
    \caption{First figure continued}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Second figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The files for the example images are available with the »[mwe](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)« package installed on your system.

---

[image]

Comment: What change should I make to the above code to change the (cont.) in the caption of the figure to simply continued without the brackets.

Comment: This unfortunately fails with subfigures in the continued float, since the modification adds `(cont.)`  to the additional subfigures captions.

Comment: @mu7z I had the same problem. You can add `\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=plain}` to the continued float, to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Before the continued figure add these lines:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure} (Cont.)}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

and after it these line:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{foo1}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure} (Cont.)}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}

\begin{figure}
\caption{foo2}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\begin{figure}
\caption{foo3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image: Output]

**EDIT** If you want to automate this you can define a new environment in your preamble using:

```
\newenvironment{Contfigure}{%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure} (Cont.)}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\begin{figure}}{%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}%
\end{figure}}
```

However even though it might make your code lighter if you have a lot of Continued Figures, it is also less flexible than the above version if you want to customize or adjust some parameters of your Figure.

Here a full MWE with the new environment for the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Contfigure}{%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure} (Cont.)}%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\begin{figure}}{%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}%
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{foo1}
\end{figure}

\begin{Contfigure}
\caption{foo2}
\end{Contfigure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{foo3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```