# Separate figure legends when using \ContinuedFloat

Tags: floats, lyx, subfig

I have a figure float with 3 subfigs in lyx which are too large to fit on one page, so am using \ContinuedFloat. The figure now goes over two pages and the figure number is the same for both, as in the screenshot.

How can I modify the second figure legend (which is a duplicate of the first) to simply read: "Figure 4 (continued)" or something similar, such that I don't have two duplicate figure legends?
Is it possible through \renewcommand somehow?

[image]

Comment: Hello, despite its unclear title, the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133113/continued-figures) seems to cover your need.

Comment: Yes that's extremely helpful. Thanks !