# Continue figure caption onto next page

Tags: floats, captions

I have been trying to get my figure caption to start on the same page as my figure but obey the margins and continue on the next page after. I have tried everything I have come across and the only solution seems to be separating the figure and the caption. The posts with code that suggest the caption can continue do not work for me. My caption is very long and I do not want to make it smaller, despite best practice.

An example similar to my code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{3GoogleStreetView/jakob-owens-1_0KyvVdtP4-unsplash.jpg}
    \caption{Image by Jakob Owens. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text}
    \label{image}
\end{figure}
```

And the result is:

[image: Jakob Owens Picture]

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: figure and caption both make boxes that can not be broken.  You could use continuedfloat from the caption package see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133113/continued-figures  but you would have to break the caption by hand, or always put it on the following page

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page  However, you may need to create a custom caption, which is not trivial but not too difficult.